# Pseudo element in after starting from center - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Following is my code in which I am trying to apply a red color bottom to a div in such a way that it takes `50px` left and right `margin` and then stretch to the max width, but somehow it is moving to the left. Let me know how can I make to appear in center to the bottom of the div with 50px space left from left and right.

Also let me know why the `::after` element is creating from the center than from the extreme left. [Refer to the image of its creation].

HTML -

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a simple heading</h1>
  <h3>This is only a test description</h3>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.container {
  background: #34EACC;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/gwdvqs5j/

IMAGE -

[image: image-alignment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While defining `absolute` you also should declare `left` or `right` properties if want to `position` the element

```css
.container {
  background: #34EACC;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a simple heading</h1>
  <h3>This is only a test description</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use left and right properties

```css
.container {
  background: #34EACC;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a simple heading</h1>
  <h3>This is only a test description</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use translate: transform(),

hope this helps :)

```css
.container {
  background: #34EACC;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>This is a simple heading</h1>
      <h3>This is only a test description</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, because while it achieves the desired goal it is not a very elegant solution (It corrects the problem *after* it has happened rather than fixing the root cause by defining the properties correctly) and transform is known to cause problems in IE (probably wouldn't in this case though).